# Codeigniter get where clause from input select

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to get database information from table by using where clause from a select options.

My view:

```
<div>
    <select name="noSeats" class="form-control" placeholder="Seats">
        <option value="">Seats</option>
        <option value="45">45</option>
        <option value="49">49</option>
        <option value="51">51</option>
        <option value="53">53</option>
        <option value="56">56</option>
        <option value="57">57</option>
        <option value="61">61</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

My Model:

```
public function getSeats($noSeats) {
    $query = $this->db->get('seat');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    }    
}
```

Also I have another problem with listing checkboxes; I need to list checkboxes in row of limit to 4 since I have many chechboxes.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function getSeats($noSeats){
      $query = $this->db->from('seat')->where('seat_col', $noSeats)->get();
      if($query->num_rows() > 0){
      return $query->result();
      }  
 }
```

Comment: I need those check boxes to appear after choosing number of seats

Comment: This function is returning the result of seats, so you can pass these seats to the view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$query = $this->db->where('COLUMN_NAME', $noSeats )->get('seat');
```